# Entidade com chave simples referenciando outra com chave composta

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou utilizando Fluent NHibernate para mapeamento das minhas classes, e tenho a seguinte situação:

Classe UsuarioMap

```
public class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        Table("USUARIOS");
        Id(x => x.ID, "USUARIO_ID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
        //Comentado para evitar código desnecessário

        References(x => x.Proprietario).Columns("PROPRIETARIO_ID", "SERVIDOR_ID");
    }
}
```

Classe ProprietarioMap:

```
public class ProprietarioMap : ClassMap<Proprietario>
{
    public ProprietarioMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();

        Table("PROPRIETARIOS");
        CompositeId().
            KeyProperty(x => x.ID, "PROPRIETARIO_ID").
            KeyProperty(x => x.ServidorId, "SERVIDOR_ID");

        Id(x => x.ID, "PROPRIETARIO_ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        //Comentado para evitar código desnecessário
    }
}
```

Ao tentar salvar um `Usuario`, recebo uma `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. O objeto que tento salvar está da seguinte maneira:

```
var usuario = new Usuario
{
    Proprietario = new Proprietario { ID = 1497196, ServidorId = 2 }
    // Comentado para evitar código desnecessário
};
```

É interessante que, se eu criar uma propriedade `ProprietarioID` na classe `Usuario` e mapeá-la, o objeto é salvo sem problemas.

O que estou fazendo de errado? O mapeamento de uma entidade composta em outra simples está correto?

Comment: É necessário o `Id(x => x.ID, "PROPRIETARIO_ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();` no mapeamento do `Proprietario`? Pois conferi com um cenário parecido que tenho aqui em meu projeto, e está muito parecido com o seu.

Comment: Oi Fernando, obrigado pela resposta.

Tentei retirar o GeneratedBy.Assigned, mas o erro persistiu...

Comment: Na tabela de `Proprietario` tem um registro com os identificadores `new Proprietario { ID = 1497196, ServidorId = 2 }`, previamente cadastrado? Não que seja isso, mas é uma possibilidade.

Comment: Sim, o registro já existe em Proprietario

Comment: Você poderia obter mais detalhes da `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, tipo capturar toda a pilha de erro. Para tentarmos descobrir a origem da `Exception`, já que [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) é uma `Exception` disparada por um argumento invalido e não nulo.

Comment: Segue então a Stack Trace gerada:

http://pastebin.com/jAjsR2C5

Comment: Alterei o mapeamento de `Proprietario` para a seguinte forma:
`References(x => x.Proprietario).Columns("PROPRIETARIO_ID", "SERVIDOR_ID").Not.Update().Not.Insert();`

O erro agora consiste em `ORA-01400: não é possível inserir NULL em ("BANCO"."USUARIOS"."PROPRIETARIO_ID")`

Comment: É possível você obter o SQL gerado pelo NHibernate antes de executar efetivamente no banco de dados? Para mostrar o SQL adicione o `.ShowSql()` em suas configurações, é algo similar a isto se você está utilizando o Oracle: `OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).ShowSql();`

Comment: Segue o SQL, que realmente não está passando o `PROPRIETARIO_ID`: http://pastebin.com/0bR7nNAK

Em relação ao cenário de mapeamento sem `.Not.Update().Not.Insert()`, nem é gerado SQL (estou verificando pelo NHibernate Profiler)

Comment: Resolvi a questão mapeando um campo privado chamado `proprietarioID`, e apontando o mapeamento para ele:
`Map(x => x.ProprietarioID).Column("PROPRIETARIO_ID").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.None);`

Na classe Usuario, alterei o construtor para receber um parâmetro do tipo Proprietario, com pelo menos ID e ServidorID, e a propriedade Proprietario agora somente possui get, onde retorno o objeto do banco.

Em todo caso, muito obrigado @Fernando pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi a questão mapeando um campo privado chamado `proprietarioID`, e apontando o mapeamento para ele:

```
Map(x => x.ProprietarioID).Column("PROPRIETARIO_ID").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.None);`
```

Na classe `Usuario`, alterei o construtor para receber um parâmetro do tipo `Proprietario`, com pelo menos `ID` e `ServidorID`, e a propriedade `Proprietario` agora somente possui get, onde retorno o objeto do banco. Em todo caso, muito obrigado @Fernando pela ajuda!

```
 public virtual Proprietario Proprietario
 {
     get
     {
         if (proprietario != null)
             return proprietario;

         if (proprietarioID == 0 || ServidorID == 0) return null;
         proprietario = new Repository<Proprietario>().Get(proprietarioID, SrvUn);
         return proprietario;
     }
 }

 public Usuario() : this(null)
 {

 }

 public Usuario(Proprietario proprietario)
 {
     if (proprietario == null) return;

     proprietarioID = proprietario.ID;
     this.proprietario = proprietario;
 }
```

Comment: Se você resolveu o problema, pode marcar sua resposta como aceita.